# Why is this query not using an index sort?

Tags: sql, select, optimization, h2

**Note**: Table/Column/Index names are made up.

#### Background

I am having some trouble figuring out how to query one of my database tables efficiently (the table has about a million rows). The query in question involves a `WHERE` clause with a foreign key and an `ORDER BY` clause with another column.

The database generates an index on the FK and I create an index on the column I will use for ordering:

```
CREATE INDEX ab ON a(b);
```

#### Problem

When I run the query without filtering on the FK:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM a ORDER BY b;
```

The database properly uses the index to sort. I know this because the result (truncated) from this query returns:

```
FROM PUBLIC.A
  /* PUBLIC.AB */
ORDER BY 3
/* index sorted */
```

However, when the query is modified to filter on the FK:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM a WHERE a_fk_id = 3 ORDER BY b
```

Only the FK index is used:

```
FROM PUBLIC.A
   /* PUBLIC.A_FK_INDEX_NAME: A_FK_ID = 3 */
WHERE A_FK_ID = 3
ORDER BY 3
```

As you can see, only the FK index is used.

#### Questions

What is going on here? 
I thought perhaps it had something to do with the separate indexes, but even creating a multi-column index like:

```
CREATE INDEX a_fk_id_b ON a(a_fk_id, b);
```

Did nothing to resolve the problem (neither did reversing the order of those columns in the index, but I didn't expect it to anyways).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am by no means a database or SQL expert, but I was surprised to get these results. Perhaps I just need to query for this information differently, but I figured this was a relatively simple case.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted and voted to be closed (as off-topic!?). I'd love to hear your reasoning. Perhaps it is due to some database ignorance on my part but I did a fair amount of research and experimentation before coming here.

Comment: have you looked into the estimated execution plan/explain query?

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Yes, the results of which I posted as part of the question (truncated). Didn't give me any insight into why my index wasn't be used, just that it wasn't. Unless you're referring to something besides my use of `EXPLAIN ...`

Comment: @Default The indexes help reduce disk access time since they point the database to where the the data is on the hard drive. If, after the where clause is applied, the results get stored in memory for sorting, the index is quite useless. I suspect that's what is happening to your second query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the answer is very simple, although not entirely obvious (at least not to me). The table needed to have a composite index between the FK and the order column:

```
CREATE INDEX a_fk_id_b ON a(a_fk_id, b);
```

And in order for the database to utilize that index instead of the generated FK index, the `a_fk_id` column needed to included in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM a WHERE a_fk_id = 3 ORDER BY a_fk_id, b;
```

This results in our composite index being used for filtering as well as for ordering as shown in this truncated explain plan:

```
FROM PUBLIC.A
   /* PUBLIC.A_FK_ID_B: A_FK_ID = 3 */
WHERE A_FK_ID = 3
ORDER BY 25, 19
/* index sorted */
```

Comment: The biggest problem here was probably just me not understanding that the database could only take advantage of one index. Therefore when I had separate indexes for both columns, it picked the best one (the FK index only) which is what caused the lack of index sorting. By forcing the use of the composite index by including the FK in the order by (though redundant) allowed the database to filter AND sort by said index.